# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException after String.split()

Tags: java

I got a string value from server:

```
String fileName = requestServer();

//My log shows fileName="properties.txt"

String name = fileName.trim().split(".")[0];
```

But when I try to get the name without ".txt" with above code, I got

```
ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0, index=0.
```

I don't see where my code is wrong, why I get this exception?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

Comment: Please note that `String#split` accepts a regex as parameter, and `.` is a special character, you need to escape it like `\\.`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This: `String name = fileName.trim().split(".")[0];` should be like so: `String name = fileName.trim().split("\\.")[0];`. The `.` in regex language means *any character* (since [`String.split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) takes a [`regular expression`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) as a parameter.), which causes the string to be split on each character thus returning an empty array.

The `\` infront of `.` will *escape* the period and cause the regex engine to treat it like an actual `.` character. The extra `\` is needed so that the initial `\` can be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
String name = fileName.trim().split("\\.")[0];
```

Explanation of the regex \.

`.` is a regex metacharacter to match anything (except newline). Since we want to match a literal . we escape it with . Since both Java Strings and regex engine use \ as escape character we need to use `\\`.

Comment: @BackSlash doesn't mean it isn't useful

Comment: @grexter89 Surely it is useful, but an answer must explain what is being done and why. Just providing code is not the purpose of this site.

Comment: @NiksTyagi Yes, now it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

`split(...)` returns an empty array, because it takes a **regex** as argument. `"."` is for every word character. The characters, that are found by that regex aren't included in the result.

Use `"\\."` instead to split.